# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle won't upload profile picture

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm creating one app using symphony 3 and FOSUserBundle.
I've created my User class with other proprieties, and one of them is a profile picture.
Here my User class:

```
#src/UserBundle/Entity/User.php
<?php
namespace UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class User extends BaseUser {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $first_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="last_name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $last_name;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="address", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="post", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $post;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="birth_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $birth_date;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="gender", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $gender;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *      maxSize = "5M",
     *      mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/tiff"},
     *      maxSizeMessage = "The maximum allowed file size is 5MB.",
     *      mimeTypesMessage = "Only the file types image are allowed.")
     */
    public $file;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAddress() {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstName() {
        return $this->first_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $first_name
     */
    public function setFirstName($first_name) {
        $this->first_name = $first_name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLastName() {
        return $this->last_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $last_name
     */
    public function setLastName($last_name) {
        $this->last_name = $last_name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $address
     */
    public function setAddress($address) {
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPost() {
        return $this->post;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $post
     */
    public function setPost($post) {
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCity() {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $city
     */
    public function setCity($city) {
        $this->city = $city;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getBirthDate() {
        return $this->birth_date;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $birth_date
     */
    public function setBirthDate($birth_date) {
        $this->birth_date = $birth_date;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGender() {
        return $this->gender;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $gender
     */
    public function setGender($gender) {
        $this->gender = $gender;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload() {
        if (null !== $this->file) {
            $this->path = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $this->file->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload() {
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }
        $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);
        unset($this->file);
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload() {
        if ($this->file == $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($this->file);
        }
    }

    public function getAbsolutePath() {
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->path;
    }

    public function getWebPath(){
        return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->id . '/' . $this->path;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir() {
        return __DIR__ . '/../../../web/' . $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->id;
    }

    protected function getUploadDir() {
        return 'uploads/users';
    }

    /**
     * @param string $path
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPath($path) {
        $this->path = $path;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath() {
        return $this->path;
    }

    public function setEmail($email) {
        $email = is_null($email) ? '' : $email;
        parent::setEmail($email);
        $this->setUsername($email);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Then I have the ProfileFormType class:

```
#src/UserBundle/Form/Type/ProfileFormType.php
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->remove('username');
        $builder->remove('current_password');
        $builder->add('first_name', TextType::class, array('label' => "First Name", 'invalid_message' => 'Please enter your First Name'));
        $builder->add('last_name', TextType::class, array('label' => "Last Name", 'invalid_message' => 'Please enter your Last Name'));
        $builder->add('address', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('post', TextType::class, array('label' => "Post Code"));
        $builder->add('city', TextType::class);
        $builder->add('gender', ChoiceType::class, array('choices' => array('Male' => 'm', 'Female' => 'f'), 'choices_as_values' => true));
        $builder->add('birth_date', DateType::class, array('label' => "Birth Date", 'widget' => 'single_text', 'invalid_message' => 'Please enter a valid date'));
        $builder->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => "Profile Picture", 'data_class' => null));
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType';
    }
}
```

My form looks something like:

```
#src/UserBundle/Resources/views/Profile/edit_content.html.twig
        {{ form_start(form, { 'action': path('fos_user_profile_edit'), 'attr': { 'class': 'fos_user_profile_edit' } }) }}
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"> Browse {{ form_widget(form.file) }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'profile.edit.submit'|trans }}" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
        {{ form_end(form) }}
```

The form is submitted correctly, and show the errors if there's some.
But the in the database, 'path' is empty and the folder (with read/write permissions) is empty.
When I add `{{ form_enctype(form) }}` to the form I got the error: `Unknown "form_enctype" function in FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit_content.html.twig`
My questions is: How can I fix this?
I can't see any error, and everything looks fine, but  it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable life cycle callbacks for your entity: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks

Comment: I added the @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks() to the top of the class, but it still the same. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Did you try to clear the Doctrine metadata cache? Can you also show your controller?

Comment: Yes I cleaned the doctrine metadata cache. I do not have controller on this bundle. Do I need to override the controller? Because all the other fields are updated (like first/last name, address, etc). But the file shouldn't be uploaded once that I have the PrePersist, PreUpdate, PostPersist and PostUpdate?

Comment: Ok, actually this is working (after adding life cycle callbacks - I'll accept your answer). The problem is that is only uploaded when I change other field. If I just choose to upload file it will not work. A work around that I read is adding another field like last updated, and change this value every time that I submit the form.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the entity is only processed by the unit of work at all if any of the mapped properties are changed. But as you need to update the `file` property you could, for example, just change that one when the path changes.